# How to use Moment.js to determine financial quarters based upon Unix timestamp?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, unix-timestamp

My goal is to compare two data sets representing financial quarters. The quirks of the API require two dates per get request: `startDate` (inclusive) and `endDate` (exclusive). Therefore, e.g., to get data for the month of July 2016 you need:

`startDate` = 20160701 and `endDate` = 20160801.

Given a single `unixStartDate` (which is a Unix timestamp), I want to find (1) the `startDate` and `endDate` for the current quarter, and (2) the `startDate` and `endDate` for the previous quarter.

So far I can use moment.js to determine the current quarter without issue:
`const currentQuarter = moment.unix(unixStartDate).utc().quarter();`
I could probably make a hacky switch-case based on that information, but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution.

Moment.js also contains `moment().startOf('quarter')`, but I've been unable to figure out its proper usage. Console.log yields an object:

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, 
_isUTC: false, 
_pf: Object, 
_locale: Locale, 
_d: Fri Jul 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT-1000 (HST)…}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a verbose version:

```
const moment = require('moment');

let unixStartDate  = ...;

let current        = moment(unixStartDate);
let currentStartOf = moment(current).startOf('quarter');
let currentEndOf   = moment(current).  endOf('quarter').add(1, 'day');

let previous        = moment(current).subtract(1, 'quarter');
let previousStartOf = moment(previous).startOf('quarter');
let previousEndOf   = moment(previous).  endOf('quarter').add(1, 'day');

console.log(
  'current ', 
  currentStartOf.format('YYYYMMDD'),
  currentEndOf  .format('YYYYMMDD')
)

console.log(
  'previous', 
  previousStartOf.format('YYYYMMDD'),
  previousEndOf  .format('YYYYMMDD')
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. One thing that I needed to adjust was to give moment a `Date` object rather than the initial `unixStartDate`.
Therefore:   
`let date = new Date(unixStartDate*1000);`  
and  
`let current = moment(date);`